# Chat multiusuario en C sin hilos

Tags: c, socket

Estoy viendo sockets en C y hasta este punto he realizado por mi cuenta varias conexiones como chats y eso, y en este caso estoy desarrollando un chat cliente-servidor multiusuarios con el uso de la herramienta `select()` la cual no logro comprender, en esta clase logramos desarrollar el siguiente servidor:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

#define TAM 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int i, s, s_conec, leido, ndesc;
unsigned int tam_dir;
struct sockaddr_in dir, dir_cliente;
char buf[TAM];
int opcion=1;
fd_set desc_sockets; 
fd_set desc_sockets_copia; 

if (argc!=2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Uso: %s puerto\n", argv[0]);
            return 1;
    }
if ((s=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) {
    perror("error creando socket");
    return 1;
}
/* Para reutilizar puerto inmediatamente */
    if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opcion, sizeof(opcion))<0){
            perror("error en setsockopt");
            return 1;
    }
dir.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
dir.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[1]));
dir.sin_family=PF_INET;
if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&dir, sizeof(dir)) < 0) {
    perror("error en bind");
    close(s);
    return 1;
}

if (listen(s, 5) < 0) {
    perror("error en listen");
    close(s);
    return 1;
}

FD_ZERO(&desc_sockets); 
FD_SET(s, &desc_sockets); 
while (1) {
    desc_sockets_copia=desc_sockets; 
    if ((ndesc=select(FD_SETSIZE, &desc_sockets_copia,
            NULL, NULL, NULL))<0) {
        perror("error en select");
        close(s);
        return 1;
    }
    if (FD_ISSET(s, &desc_sockets_copia)) {
        ndesc--;

        tam_dir=sizeof(dir_cliente);
        if ((s_conec=accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&dir_cliente,
                 &tam_dir))<0){
            perror("error en accept");
            close(s);
            return 1;
        }
        FD_SET(s_conec, &desc_sockets); 
    }
    for (i=0; ndesc; i++) {
        if (FD_ISSET(i, &desc_sockets_copia)) {
            ndesc--;
            if ((leido=read(i, buf, TAM))>0) {
                if (write(i, buf, leido)<0) {
                    perror("error en write");
                    close(s);
                    return 1;
                }
            }

            if (leido<0) {
                perror("error en read");
                close(s);
                return 1;
            }
            if (leido==0) { // cliente cierra conexión
                close(i);
                FD_CLR(i, &desc_sockets); 
            }
        }
    }
}

close(s);

return 0;
}
```

Pero esto fue con ayuda. Actualmente estoy tratando de hacer un cliente para este código pero simplemente no entiendo muy bien las funciones ni cómo se comportan. Si pudieran darme el empujoncito que necesito lo agradecería totalmente, para poder entender.

Comment: ¿ Cual es la pregunta ?

Comment: _estoy tratando de hacer un cliente para este codigo pero simplemente no entiendo muy bien las funciones ni como se comportan_: recuerda mencionar el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. Actualmente, no hay pregunta como para responder.

Comment: Por otro lado, si tu problema es que no entiendes cómo funcionan los sockets, tal vez debas recurrir a Internet o a libros especializados sobre el tema. Los sockets es un tema bastante extenso y una simple respuesta no alcanzaría para abarcarlo